# Trying to Create Android Binding Library For MoPub

Tags: android, xamarin, mopub

I am trying to create a binding library in Xamarin for MoPub.  I actually have this working great. But now I want to implement mediation. I have added the GooglePlayServicesBanner.java file to the mopub SDK and the google play services library:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

But no matter what I do, the binding library cannot find "AdListener"

```
1>JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class com/mopub/mobileads/GooglePlayServicesBanner$AdViewListener : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener
```

Here are a few reasons why this may be happening:

1. I need to include the google play services jar file to the libs directory in my library project.  But GPS only offers an aar so I dont know what to do about that.
2. Something is getting stripped by proguard
3. Something is goofy in my Xamarin metadata.xml

I am stuck and hopefully someone has some insight.  Thanks!

Here is the Xamarin stacktrace when an Admob ad is attempted to be displayed.

```
12-08 15:26:32.886 D/MoPub   ( 3378): Loading custom event adapter.
12-08 15:26:32.886 D/MoPub   ( 3378): Attempting to invoke custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner$AdViewListener>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener;
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String) (Class.java:326)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerFactory.internalCreate(java.lang.String) (CustomEventBannerFactory.java:20)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerFactory.create(java.lang.String) (CustomEventBannerFactory.java:11)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter.<init>(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, long, com.mopub.common.AdReport) (CustomEventBannerAdapter.java:61)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.internalCreate(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, long, com.mopub.common.AdReport) (CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.java:32)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.create(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, long, com.mopub.common.AdReport) (CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.java:24)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Object com.mopub.common.util.Reflection$MethodBuilder.execute() (Reflection.java:71)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.loadCustomEvent(java.lang.String, java.util.Map) (MoPubView.java:188)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.loadCustomEvent(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map) (AdViewController.java:177)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.onAdLoadSuccess(com.mopub.network.AdResponse) (AdViewController.java:136)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1.onSuccess(com.mopub.network.AdResponse) (AdViewController.java:107)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.network.AdRequest.deliverResponse(com.mopub.network.AdResponse) (AdRequest.java:310)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.network.AdRequest.deliverResponse(java.lang.Object) (AdRequest.java:46)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run() (ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:865)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:755)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kellyproductions.minechatlite-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kellyproductions.minechatlite-1/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.kellyproductions.minechatlite-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String) (Class.java:326)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerFactory.internalCreate(java.lang.String) (CustomEventBannerFactory.java:20)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerFactory.create(java.lang.String) (CustomEventBannerFactory.java:11)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter.<init>(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, long, com.mopub.common.AdReport) (CustomEventBannerAdapter.java:61)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.internalCreate(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, long, com.mopub.common.AdReport) (CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.java:32)
12-08 15:26:32.891 I/art     ( 3378):   at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter com.mopub.mobileads.factories.CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.create(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map, long, com.mopub.common.AdReport) (CustomEventBannerAdapterFactory.java:24)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Object com.mopub.common.util.Reflection$MethodBuilder.execute() (Reflection.java:71)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.loadCustomEvent(java.lang.String, java.util.Map) (MoPubView.java:188)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.loadCustomEvent(com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView, java.lang.String, java.util.Map) (AdViewController.java:177)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.onAdLoadSuccess(com.mopub.network.AdResponse) (AdViewController.java:136)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1.onSuccess(com.mopub.network.AdResponse) (AdViewController.java:107)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.network.AdRequest.deliverResponse(com.mopub.network.AdResponse) (AdRequest.java:310)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.network.AdRequest.deliverResponse(java.lang.Object) (AdRequest.java:46)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.mopub.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run() (ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:865)
12-08 15:26:32.892 I/art     ( 3378):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: 1. an aar is just an enhanced jar with android resources. What ever you would do with the jar you can do with aar as well. 2. maybe you share your proguard config? We can't guess what you have defined there. Also tried it with minify = false? 3. Maybe you share your xml file as well? We can't guess that too

Comment: Thanks Warren.  I found one of the issues.  You must include the Google play components in the Xamarin binding library before compiling.  That fixed this issue but now I am running to other issues that may be related to proguard. Will have to make another post for that.

Answer (score 1):

You must include the Google play components in the Xamarin binding library before compiling. That fixed this issue.